# Failed import of date using COPY

Tags: postgresql, import, postgresql-9.5, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a table in Postgres, and it's bombing out on the first date field. The dates are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and there isn't a date in the field in question in the CSV.

As such I'm using the following:

```
set datestyle = 'ISO,DMY'; 

\copy companies_house_snapshot 
FROM 'BasicCompanyDataAsOneFile-2017-04-01.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL AS '';
```

Which I thought should be sufficient, the error message is:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""  
> CONTEXT:  COPY companies_house_snapshot, line 2, column dissolution_date: ""
> ```

Where `dissolution_date` is nullable and in the CSV as `""`

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Where am I going wrong?

If I use `'""'` as `NULL`, I get:

> ```
> ERROR:  CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification
> ```

Comment: Remove `CSV` and `NULL AS '""'` is possible ; but `HEADER` is not possible without `CSV`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that

Comment: You can't use `NULL AS '""'` with the `CSV` option, but you can without it. But you use `HEADER` which could be use only with `CSV`. You have to choose between `NULL AS '""'` and `HEADER`. You can preprocess your file to remove the first line, by example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use '""' as NULL, I get:

I get these issues all the time. PostgreSQL has made a really massive and stupid mistake from a UI perspective by having two modes

1. CSV
2. NON-CSV

CSV according to them is [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). However, it's not all that useful to adhere to a spec if no one else does and RFC4180 is probably the least used spec on the internet. **Start using it people.**

Anyway to solve these problems the easy method is to create a test table...

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x int, y int, z int );
INSERT INTO foo (x,y,z) VALUES (1,null,2);
```

And then to get to work brute forcing options for both modes. That's why I do anyway because I find it so unintuitive. It's pretty quick though.

```
COPY foo TO STDOUT NULL AS '""' DELIMITER ',';
```

That seems to do what you want. You should be able to read it with the same options.

```
COPY foo FROM '/tmp/test.csv' NULL AS '""' DELIMITER ',';
```